# PHP- Zend Framework- Call action from another action's view on CentOS Server

Tags: php, zend-framework, action, centos, call

I deploying my PHP project on CentOS and i using Zend Framework.

**I have problem**:

When i call an action from another action's view and it displayed is good on Windows Server but not good on CentOS Server. It's not load info in head tag when view source html.

**Example**:

In file: *index.phtml* (for index action in Product controller)

```
<div class="left">
     <?php echo $this->action('left', $this->controller,'product',array('currentModule'=>$this->module)); ?>
</div>
<div class='right'>
    <?php echo $this->action('list', $this->controller, 'product',array('currentModule'=>$this->module,'back'=> $this->back,'page'=> $this->page)); ?>
</div>
```

So, we can see. In index.phtml, i called 2 another action (*left action and list action in Product controller*). *Windows is OK but on CentOS, this code is not work.*

**Please help me for it run on CentOS.**

When i was try remove 2 this action:

```
<div class="left">
     //code 
  </div>
    <div class='right'>
       //code 
    </div>
```

So, it's woking on CentOS :)

Thanks!

Comment: So wait, is it working on CentOS or not?

Comment: Hi jprofitt, i want it running on CentOS, currently it's not woking on CentOS.
Plz help me!

Comment: Sounds like a PHP config issue on your CentOS server... How did you install PHP? Are the versions the same?

Comment: My customer was required: Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.3.13, MySql 5.5.23 and i installed them.

Comment: All another module is OK but only this module have a issue. When i debug, i detected issue raise on this line that's call action.

Comment: This issue only occur when i call multi action in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Windows migrations to unix based systems usually run into problems like this when you have case sensitivity issues - windows doesn't require case to be correct but unix does. Make sure your folders and php file names have the correct case and try it again - if not give us some of the errors your encountering and we could help more!

By the way, a little off topic here but the action view helper is not efficient, I would suggest looking into custom view helpers and the render view helper instead.

Comment: Thank williamvicary, i will trying build demo version for you.